# Como redirecionar usuário para pagina após login?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Web, utilizando `Asp.Net MVC 5 com Identity` e estou utilizando `Roles` para realizar a autorização.

Estou tentando fazer que dependendo da `Role` que o usuário tiver, ele é direcionado para uma pagina "Home" diferente.

Exemplo:

- Administradores => Home da Administração;
- Vendedores => Home do Comercial.

E por assim vai. Mas estou com dificuldades de achar uma solução.

Para redirecionar o usuario quando tiver acesso negado pelas `Roles`, eu sub-escrevi o método `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`:

```
  protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // The user is not authenticated
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else if (!this.Roles.Split(',').Any(filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole))
        {
            // The user is not in any of the listed roles => 
            // show the unauthorized view
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Page_403.cshtml"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Agora, para realizar esse redirecionamento, após efetuar o login? como faria?

Código do Controller `Account`:

```
        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```

Ao tentar validar utilizando a condição: `if(UserManager.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "admin"))`
foi gerado o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da `HomeController`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [PermissoesFiltro]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [PermissoesFiltro(Roles = "Comercial")]
    public ActionResult Index_Comercial()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [PermissoesFiltro(Roles = "Master")]
    public ActionResult Index_Master()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Tabelas do Identity:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não postou o código onde você valida o login, você está usando `FormsAuth.SignIn`? Mas bastaria executar um `RedirectToAction`. Pode explicar melhor seu problema?

Comment: @RicardoPontual fiz uma revisão e postei o código do controller, Estou utilizando o padrão que vem com identity, que apôs o login redireciona para a home default. Minha duvida, é como verificar a `Role` do usuário e direcionar para paginas diferentes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe uma propriedade do *controller* chamada **`User`**, <strike>assim que o login for realizado com sucesso essa propriedade passará a ter um valor (informações sobre a identidade do usuário logado).</strike> Isso não é bem verdade, vide atualização logo abaixo;

Esta propriedade vai ser "alimentada" pelo Identity e precisa implementar a interface `IPrincipal`. Nesta interface, existe o método `IsInRole(string role)`  que é exatamente o que você precisa.

Vou focar na parte do código que realmente interessa, o que vai ser feito aí dentro depende do que é realmente necessário pro seu projeto, podes fazer uma consulta no banco pra recuperar a URL, podes fazer mais validações. O importante é entender que `User.IsInRole` serve exatamente para o que você precisa.

```
case SignInStatus.Success:
    {        
        if(User.IsInRole("Admin")) // Se o usuário estiver na role admin
            return RedirectToLocal("UrlAdmin"); //Redireciona para uma URL pré-definida
        
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);    
    }
```

---

#### Atualização

Na verdade, a propriedade `User` ainda está vazia no momento do Login, então, será necessário uma outra estratégia para recuperar o usuário que está logando no momento.

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password); 

if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin"))
    return RedirectToAction("Home_Admin", "Controller"); //A forma de redirect que irá usar
```

**`UserManager`** é uma propriedade do `AccountController`.

Comment: Sim, já conferi o nome da `role` e esta ok, no momento estou registrando o usuário na role diretamente via banco, não tenho métodos implantado para isso ainda.

Comment: Fiz uma revisão na perguntando, adicionando o erro que foi gerado, ao tentar validar dessa maneira.

Comment: Estou utilizando a implantação default do Identity, unica coisa que fiz foi ter alterado o design da view.

Comment: Sim, posso, ja conferi as tabelas do identity e aparentemente estão ok, estou tentando igual você falou em uma aplicação nova, ou seja sem modificação nenhuma, tambem adicionei um print das tabelas na pergunta

Comment: Amigo, perfeito, agora funcionou, somente para eu entender, você buscou o usuario pelo email e pelo password e depois verificou se ele tinha a `role` certo?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar sobrescrever o método de autorização `OnAuthorization`, passando os valores das rotas, por padrão são três valores de rota: `controller`, `action` e `area`, este último se houver uma área. Como você já sobrescreveu o método `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`, fica coerente sobrescrever a autorização também, deixando num mesmo local o tratamento de redirecionamentos.

```
 public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var dicRota = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            dicRota.Add("controller", "Admin");
            dicRota.Add("action", "Home");
        }
        else if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Vendedores"))
        {
            dicRota.Add("controller", "Comercial");
            dicRota.Add("action", "Home");
        }

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(dicRota));
    }
```

Comment: Amigo, ao tentar utilizar a sua solução, a condição `If` da certo, ou seja, ele consegue verificar a `role` do usuário, porem, não acessa `view`, fala que não pode ser exibida, ja testei as `view` e estão funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Você passou no dicionários os nomes corretos dos controllers e actions? Nos meus exemplos eu assumo que haja os controllers Admin e Comercial, com as respectivas ações Home.

Comment: Sim, foi passado nome do controller = "home" nome da action = "index_comercial" e "index_master"

Comment: Precisava dar uma olhada no arquivo HomeController.cs. Se nele tiver `public ActionResult index_comercial(){ return View(); } ` era pra funcionar.

Comment: Fiz uma revisão, colocando o codigo.